# "Combo-box" for ArcGIS Java script API (ver. 3.1)

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I am using combo-box in ArcGIS Java script API (ver.2.8). When I update the version to 3.1 it gives an error "TypeError: _2d.store.query is not a function"

Can anybody tell me that "Combo-box" effect is removed in 3.1 version ??

I am trying to make similar type example (Click [here](http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2010/08/30/populate-a-combo-box-with-unique-values-using-a-query-layer/))

Any help will be great...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The newer Javascript api uses the newer versions of ItemFileReadStore and ItemFileWriteStore, which has been re-organized under dojo.data, instead of dojo.store. Check that you're referencing dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore and dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore to store your results, and replace any references to dojo.store.ItemFileReadStore and dojo.store.ItemFileWriteStore.

Comment: thanks for your reply..it works now for version 3.1 : ) thanks